# Outer ListView.ItemClick event happening before inner Grid.Tapped but not inner Button.Tapped

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

Given the following XAML:

```
<ListView IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Tapped="Button_Tapped" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <x:String>hello</x:String>
    <x:String>world</x:String>
</ListView>
```

If I click a button, the `Button_Tapped` handler is executed and then `ListView_ItemClick` is not executed at all (regardless of whether or not `e.Handled` is set to true in the `Button_Tapped` handler). If I do not click a button, but I click within the list view item, then `ListView_ItemClick` will be executed. This behavior is ok.

But if replace the button for a grid like this:

```
<ListView IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10" Background="Red" IsTapEnabled="True" Tapped="Grid_Tapped" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <x:String>hello</x:String>
    <x:String>world</x:String>
</ListView>
```

and then I click on a grid, `ListView_ItemClick` will be executed first and then `Grid_Tapped`. Why is this happening? How to I get the events to fire in the correct order like in the first example with the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button handles the pointer events to trigger its own Click event, so the ListView never gets them to trigger its event.

In almost all cases I'd recommend using a Button and handling Click rather than handling Tapped. This is better for accessibility since the Button has built-in support both for keyboard focus and for click semantics. It is much easier to template the Button to fit your UI than it is to implement your own focus handling and InvokePattern.